# scrollViewDidScroll not getting called

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, delegates

I have a `UIViewController` that is a delegate of a `UIScrollView` called `NumberLineScroll`. I have set the delegate of the scrollview to be the view controller, but I am not getting any calls to `scrollViewDidScroll:` whenever the scrollview is scrolled. Here's the implementation:

The `UIViewController` header file (`Game`) :

```
@interface Game : UIViewController <LocDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, ResultsDelegate> {
    ... 
    NumberLineScroll* nline;
    ...
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale;
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

and the component of the main file where the methods are implemented:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

...
nline = [[NumberLineScroll alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, -50, 1024, 400)];
[nline setScrollEnabled:YES];
[nline setContentSize:CGSizeMake(4100, 400)];
[self.view addSubview:nline];
nline.delegate = self;
nline.locDelegate = self; //this is for a Ball imageview that is implemented in NumberLineScroll
...

}
```

and here's the implementation of the `UIScrollView` (`NumberLineScroll`):

header file:

```
@interface NumberLineScroll : UIScrollView {

    NumberLine* nline;
    Ball* ball;
    id <UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
    id <LocDelegate> locDelegate;
}

@property(nonatomic, assign)id <UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;
@property(nonatomic, assign)id <LocDelegate> locDelegate;
```

There's nothing that's very relevant in the main file. The only programming in there that I do to affect the scrolling is turn the bounce off and to switch the scrolling off when the ball is being moved by the user, then on again when they finish. Also, the `locDelegate` isn't a problem since that works just fine. The main problem is that `NumberLineScroll` is making no delegate calls. Why is this?

Also, the `NumberLine` view in `NumberLineScroll` is the contentview for the scrollview, just for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess here is that you're redefining the `delegate` property inside you `NumberLineScroll` class. Try deleting the `@property(nonatomic, assign)id <UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;` line (and if you have a `@synthesize` statement in your *.m file delete that one too). Also, delete the following variable declaration: `id <UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate;`.

Finally, just as a side comment, when you conform to a protocol (like `UIScrollViewDelegate`) you don't declare the methods that you implement in your *.h file. So, the following lines in your `Game` class are not needed:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView*)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale;
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
```

Hope this helps!